# How do I "bin" results in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I am trying to bin my results so my groupings have lower granularity - going from a 1-10 scale to a 1-5 scale.
For example, any result 1 or 2 would be renamed to 1 in the next column, any result 3 or 4 would be renamed to 2 in the next column, ...

I have tried:

```
=lookup(F3{=10,=9,=8,=7,=6,=5,=4,=3,=2,=1},G3{5,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1})
```

and get a formula parse error.

Can you help?

Comment: How about just dividing and rounding?

Answer (score 0):

I think `LOOKUP` is maybe overkill to do this ?
Try instead this :

```
=ROUND(range/2,0)
```

Example 1

```
Entry      Result
  10    |    5
  9     |    5
  8     |    4
  7     |    4
  6     |    3
  5     |    3
  4     |    2
  3     |    2
  2     |    1
  1     |    1
```

Formula used in `B1` : `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUND(A1:A10/2,0))`

---

**Edit** : if you want to use `LOOKUP`, try to sort in ascending order the first range.
Example 2

```
Entry      Result
  1     |    1
  2     |    1
  3     |    2
  4     |    2
  5     |    3
  6     |    3
  7     |    4
  8     |    4
  9     |    5
  10    |    5
```

Tests :
`=LOOKUP(5, $A$1:$A$10, $B$1:$B$10)` | Result is `3`
`=LOOKUP(9, $A$1:$A$10, $B$1:$B$10)` | Result is `9`
`=LOOKUP(3, $A$1:$A$10, $B$1:$B$10)` | Result is `2`

`=LOOKUP("string", $A$1:$A$10, $B$1:$B$10)` | **Error**
Did not find value *'string'* in `LOOKUP` evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 {1, 1; 
  3, 2; 
  5, 3; 
  7, 4; 
  9, 5}, 2)))
```

[image]